# usar método do serviço WCF devolve The caller was not authenticated by the service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-service, soap, wcf

Tenho um projeto com vários serviços WCF compilado, e acessível por outro projeto na mesma máquina. Agora estou tentando ligar-me a um desses serviços de uma outra máquina. Coloquei o URL do service refence, porém ele pede-me autenticação. O que devo fazer para me puder ligar ao serviço? Tenho todas os métodos disponíveis, mas na hora de correr o programa da-me o erro de autenticação. Tenho o serviço no web.config assim:

```
  <!--Companies Service-->
  <service name="BusinessServicesImplementation.CompaniesService"
           behaviorConfiguration="BusinessServicesImplementation.GeneralServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="wsHttpTransactionalBinding"
              contract="BusinessServicesImplementation.ICompanyService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
```

No lado do cliente tenho:

```
<binding name="WSHttpBinding_ICompanyService" transactionFlow="true" />
...
<endpoint address="http://URLEXTERIORÀMÁQUINA/Services/CompaniesService.svc"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ICompanyService"
          contract="CompaniesService.ICompanyService" name="WSHttpBinding_ICompanyService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
```

No projeto da mesma máquina do serviço tenho a address no endpoint como `localhost`, o resto está tudo igual e funciona já há muitos anos (estava feito há muito tempo, antes de eu entrar para a empresa). Como posso resolver? Obrigado

Comment: essa máquina em q os serviços estão hospedados usa IIS? Está habilitado *anonymous authentication* se for no IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Talvez seja o firewall da máquina que está impedindo as requisições de entrada. Verifica qual a porta o serviço está usando e libera ela no firewall do Windows.